# Whitelisting IP addresses in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have just finished following what appeared to be a straightforward tutorial at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-whitelist-ip-range
But once again I have found myself going around in circles trying to get it to work and wondered if anyone could help.

I'm trying to set up an IP address whitelist to access anything under /admin. Then the rest of the paths can be access by anyone.

I can confirm that breakpoints 1,2 are fired but the important breakpoint 3 is never reached. Everything under /admin is access-denied. I don't have any other authentication stuff configured. Anyone know what is going on?

So have **SecurityConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomIpAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       // 1
       auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
          .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

**CustomIpAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomIpAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

   private Set<String> whitelist = new HashSet<String>();

    public CustomIpAuthenticationProvider() {
        // 2
        whitelist.add("x.x.x.x");
    }

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
      // 3
      WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
      String userIp = details.getRemoteAddress();
      if(! whitelist.contains(userIp)){
          throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid IP Address");
      }
      return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return true; // or false, doesn't make any difference
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `.formLogin()` in your SecurityConfig. Can you provide more detail on the request you're initiating in your test. For example, are you submitting to /login?

Comment: I wanted the request to hit the protected page and allow the client to view the page if the IP address is in the list. There are no usernames or passwords and nowhere to submit them.

Comment: The only way `CustomIpAuthenticationProvider.authenticate()` will get called is during an authentication request. Given that your `SecurityConfig` is not configured for `formLogin` or `httpBasic` (or another authentication mechanism) the `AuthenticationProvider` will never get called. `AuthenticationProvider`'s only get called during an authentication process. For example, configuring `formLogin()` and sending a request to `/login` with `username` and `password` request parameters will trigger `formLogin` authentication. Makes sense?

Comment: Also take a look at `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/foo").hasIpAddress("192.168.1.0/24")` and in the [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access-web). This might help as well for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can't use `.formLogin()` because there are no users. Don't think I can use `.httpBasic()` for the same reason. So what do I put in there instead to tell it to use my authenticationProvider?

Comment: Again, `AuthenticationProvider`(s) only get called during an authentication process. If the request does not trigger an authentication process using `formLogin()` or `httpBasic` or any other authentication mechanism than `AuthenticationProvider`(s) do not get called. If you're simply looking to do basic IP whitelisting per request than you can just implement a `Filter`, given that you don't have any users as you mentioned.

Comment: @JoeGrandja I had a misunderstanding. I thought that `authorizeRequests` was a set of authorized requests i.e. the function performed by `formLogin` or `httpBasic` had already been done. What I should have done is written my http authenticator with my rules or as you say written a `Filter`. If you write something like this as an answer, then I'll accept and we can close this question.